# Multiple Controller instances Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chat

I currently have a Chat application which opens a new Chatwindow for every Chat (just like on facebook & co). To get this working so far I did some weird hacks since all of the n open chatwindows use the same $scope Variables. This is neither good programming nor does it help with bugfixing later on.

Therefore I'd like to redesign the chat part of my application and use one `MessageCtrl` instance for every Chatwindow. Is this possible in angular.js and if yes, how could I implement it?

If not, can you give me some guidelines on how to implement it "the angular way"?

**edit:** What I'm currently doing:

I create the Chatwindow from the `MessageCtrl` and save the necessary data into a `MessageService`. Since the next time a user writes a message in one of the Chatwindows I dont know if the $scope Variables are set correctly I check the `MessageService` again to find the correct Chat.

The problem is currently the only way of knowing what the correct chat is for me by saving the chat id in the parent `<div id=<chatId>` of the chatwindow. Thats far from good, but the only solution I got working so far

**edit2:** my code:

When a user starts a new Chat the following happens in some Ctrl:

```
`$rootScope.newChat = {roomId: roomId};
```

the `MessageCtrl` listens on this:

```
$rootScope.$watch('newChat', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  startChatWindow();
  // other preperation like setting $scope.roomId
}
```

`startChatWindow()` just appends the following html:

```
var $el = "<div id='" + $scope.roomId + "'class='bottomChat'>";
<!-- other things, like displaying the old messages -->
</div>";
$("#messageTab").append($compile($el)($scope));
```

PS: by chatwindow I just mean a visually appearing window, in reality it's just a  styled like a window. This also means that every chatwindow uses the same messageCtrl. Which also means that I loose reference to e.g. `$scope.roomId`

---

**edit3: SOLUTION**

after removing the jQuery code and creating a directive every chatWindow has it's own Ctrl.

Comment: How are you generating chat windows? Are they bootstrap modals or something.

Comment: they are just normal `<div>` styled to be placed fixed on the bottom of the page

Comment: You can use a controllee multiple time. It will always create a new instance and won't reuse old ones. Each of your chatwindows will have its own controller instance. But what do mean by 'open a new window'? Do you open a new browser window? In this case you load the whole html and js from the server and the window will just start another angular application with its own context.

Comment: We're missing some vital information that could help us identify what is actually going on in your code.  What 'weird hacks' are you using now, and what led you to believe that they were necessary?  Code samples say about 10 times as much as a paragraph, especially in this case.

Comment: when you say you "don't know if the `$scope` variables are set correctly", that sets off red flags for me as to how your controller is actually designed in the first place.

Comment: I just added some code of my implementation. But at the moment I'm looking for a guideline how I can actually manage to have multiple Ctrl instances since this is at the moment not the case

Comment: seems as though you have a lot of things going on here that aren't angular, so it's really hard to provide a solution.  you are using JQuery to modify the HTML directly, which will indeed break the two way binding Angular provides.  In most cases, you should **only** be doing this in a directive; if you indeed are using a directive, it should have an isolate scope.  Can you show the directive definition (if you have a directive here)?

Comment: it's really not clear what you mean by knowing which chat is which either; are you having multiple chat boxes on the page? or are you having trouble identifying which user posted to a page being broadcast to other users? are you trying to implement some sort of socket style communication between multiple users here?  I'm struggling to understand what the full process here is.

Comment: Thank you Claies for your comments, they helped me out a lot! I didn't use a directive and exactly that was the problem.